# Submit Button doesn't re-enable using an IIFE

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple contact form with the submit button disabled until all field have atleast 1 character in them.

I have some code here that works outside of an IIFE but when I put it in one, breaks the submit function. At this point, I haven't been around Javascript/jQuery long enough to restructure my code to work.

JavaScript

```
(function() {

    function init() {
        window.onload = checkform;
    }

    function checkform() {

        var validateBeforeSubmit = document.forms["contactForm"].elements;
        var cansubmit = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < validateBeforeSubmit.length; i++) {
            if (validateBeforeSubmit[i].value.length == 0)
                cansubmit = false;
        }
        document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = !cansubmit;
    }
    init();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function() { 
function init() { 
window.onload = checkform; 
} 
function checkform() { 
var validateBeforeSubmit = document.forms["contactForm"].elements;
 var cansubmit = true;
 for (var i = 0; i < validateBeforeSubmit.length; i++) {
       if (validateBeforeSubmit[i].value.length == 0) cansubmit = false; 
       validateBeforeSubmit[i].oninput=checkform;//the line you need
}    
 document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = !cansubmit; 
} 
init(); 
})();
```

I think you had sth like this before:

```
<input onchange="checkform">
```

This wouldnt work anymore because checkform isnt in the global scope anymore, its only bound via closures now...

Comment: This fixed the issue after filling in all fields and clicking out of the last field that was filled in. Is there a way to enable submit the instant there is a character in the field and not clicking out of it first?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning your **checkform** function to **onload** event. Which runs only once, when page loads.

You need to map it to to something else.
Probably on input change?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the onload event to checkform function, but who will trigger the onload event?? The browser is already triggered this event, so obviously your function never be called.

Comment: right, so I would need something to call it again to check all the fields, correct?

Comment: Nope. Kirans statement is probably wrong. The iife executes very fast it should bind the onload before it is fired...